# How transform a video and export the new file with reasonable process time

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

In my Android app, I need to apply some transformations (scale/crop) on mp4 videos.
I tried to use the FFMPEG library but the execution time is very VERY slow (average speed 1x) because it needs to reencode the video when using filtering. Here's a command I use

```
-y -ss ${startTimeString} -i ${inputPath} -t ${durationTimeString} -vf "scale='min(720,iw)':'min(1280,ih)'" -preset ultrafast ${outPath}
```

It takes about 15 min to process a 15min video. That's not bearable for my users.

I'd need a solution to apply my transformation without reencoding the video. What are the other solutions to reach my expectations?

Note that on iOS I managed to do it with the native AVFoundation library simply by applying transformations to the video layer (so without any reencoding), is there any equivalent on Android?

FYI, here's the FFMPEG stacktrace

```
    I/mobile-ffmpeg: Loading mobile-ffmpeg.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 264 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=4413ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=12249774698887, Vsync=12254174698711, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=12254182592086, AnimationStart=12254182609837, PerformTraversalsStart=12254183464633, DrawStart=12254183595751, SyncQueued=12254185475418, SyncStart=12254185925872, IssueDrawCommandsStart=12254185967779, SwapBuffers=12254187013958, FrameCompleted=12254188427920, DequeueBufferDuration=499000, QueueBufferDuration=378000, 
I/mobile-ffmpeg: Loaded mobile-ffmpeg-min-gpl-x86-4.4-lts-20210207.
D/mobile-ffmpeg: Callback thread started.
I/mobile-ffmpeg: ffmpeg version v4.4-dev-416
     Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
I/mobile-ffmpeg:   built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
I/mobile-ffmpeg:   configuration: --cross-prefix=i686-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=i686 --cpu=i686 --cc=i686-linux-android16-clang --cxx=i686-linux-android16-clang++ --extra-libs='-L/storage/light/projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --disable-neon --disable-asm --disable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-gpl --disable-sdl2 --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
      libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
      libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
      libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
      libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
      libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg: ffmpeg version v4.4-dev-416
     Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
I/mobile-ffmpeg:   built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
I/mobile-ffmpeg:   configuration: --cross-prefix=i686-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=i686 --cpu=i686 --cc=i686-linux-android16-clang --cxx=i686-linux-android16-clang++ --extra-libs='-L/storage/light/projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --disable-neon --disable-asm --disable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-gpl --disable-sdl2 --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
      libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
      libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
      libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
      libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
      libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
      libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file:///data/user/0/com.myapp/cache/videos-clip/8ed5e6dd7f2191f219776916ee7f08e5':
      Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     major_brand     : 
    isom
        minor_version   : 
    512
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     compatible_brands: 
    isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : 
    Lavf58.20.100
      Duration: 
I/mobile-ffmpeg: 00:14:54.94
    , start: 
    0.000000
I/mobile-ffmpeg: , bitrate: 
    2817 kb/s
        Stream #0:0
    (und)
I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1080x1920, 2682 kb/s
    , 
    25 fps, 
    25 tbr, 
    12800 tbn, 
I/mobile-ffmpeg: 50 tbc
     (default)
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
I/mobile-ffmpeg: Core Media Video
        Stream #0:1
    (und)
    : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s
     (default)
        Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg:       handler_name    : 
    Core Media Audio
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0
     (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1
     (aac (native) -> aac (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'file:///data/user/0/com.myapp/cache/videos-clip/8ed5e6dd7f2191f219776916ee7f08e5':
      Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     major_brand     : 
    isom
        minor_version   : 
    512
        compatible_brands: 
    isomiso2avc1mp41
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     encoder         : 
    Lavf58.20.100
      Duration: 
I/mobile-ffmpeg: 00:14:54.94
    , start: 
    0.000000
    , bitrate: 
    2817 kb/s
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #0:0
    (und)
    : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1080x1920, 2682 kb/s
    , 
    25 fps, 
    25 tbr, 
    12800 tbn, 
    50 tbc
     (default)
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    Core Media Video
        Stream #0:1
    (und)
I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s
     (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    Core Media Audio
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0
     (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
      Stream #0:1 -> #0:1
I/mobile-ffmpeg:  (aac (native) -> aac (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
W/mobile-ffmpeg: [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xbe5ef7e0] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
W/mobile-ffmpeg: [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xbfb47260] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xbe7f3800] using cpu capabilities: none!
I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xbe7f3800] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xbe7f3800] 264 - core 160 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
    Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/files/Movies/clipVideo42414368565467115200.mp4':
I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     major_brand     : 
    isom
        minor_version   : 
    512
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     compatible_brands: 
    isomiso2avc1mp41
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     encoder         : 
    Lavf58.48.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #0:0
    (und)
    : Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280, q=-1--1
    , 
    25 fps, 
I/mobile-ffmpeg: 12800 tbn, 
    25 tbc
     (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    Core Media Video
          encoder         : 
    Lavc58.96.100 libx264
        Side data:
          
    cpb: 
I/mobile-ffmpeg: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 
    vbv_delay: N/A
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #0:1
I/mobile-ffmpeg: (und)
I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
     (default)
I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
I/mobile-ffmpeg: Core Media Audio
I/mobile-ffmpeg:       encoder         : 
    Lavc58.96.100 aac
    [libx264 @ 0xb9bde000] using cpu capabilities: none!
I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xb9bde000] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xb9bde000] 264 - core 160 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
I/mobile-ffmpeg: Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/files/Movies/clipVideo44177005536261563226.mp4':
      Metadata:
        major_brand     : 
    isom
        minor_version   : 
    512
        compatible_brands: 
    isomiso2avc1mp41
        encoder         : 
    Lavf58.48.100
        Stream #0:0
    (und)
    : Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280, q=-1--1
    , 
    25 fps, 
    12800 tbn, 
    25 tbc
     (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    Core Media Video
          encoder         : 
I/mobile-ffmpeg: Lavc58.96.100 libx264
        Side data:
          
    cpb: 
I/mobile-ffmpeg: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 
    vbv_delay: N/A
        Stream #0:1
    (und)
    : Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
     (default)
        Metadata:
          handler_name    : 
    Core Media Audio
          encoder         : 
    Lavc58.96.100 aac
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.34 bitrate=   1.1kbits/s speed=0.628x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   14 fps= 13 q=21.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.67 bitrate=   0.6kbits/s speed=0.641x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   30 fps= 19 q=19.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:01.30 bitrate=1613.1kbits/s speed=0.82x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   44 fps= 21 q=21.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:01.85 bitrate=2258.1kbits/s speed=0.89x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   54 fps= 21 q=20.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:02.27 bitrate=2765.0kbits/s speed=0.88x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   68 fps= 22 q=22.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:02.83 bitrate=2961.3kbits/s speed=0.916x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   88 fps= 24 q=22.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:03.62 bitrate=3473.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  103 fps= 25 q=22.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:04.22 bitrate=3473.8kbits/s speed=1.02x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  119 fps= 26 q=20.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:04.87 bitrate=3440.7kbits/s speed=1.04x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  127 fps= 25 q=19.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:05.17 bitrate=3645.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  142 fps= 25 q=21.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:05.78 bitrate=3627.2kbits/s speed=1.02x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  161 fps= 26 q=20.0 size=    2816kB time=00:00:06.54 bitrate=3523.1kbits/s speed=1.06x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  177 fps= 26 q=22.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:07.19 bitrate=3496.2kbits/s speed=1.07x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  184 fps= 26 q=22.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:07.47 bitrate=3646.4kbits/s speed=1.04x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  196 fps= 25 q=22.0 size=    3584kB time=00:00:07.94 bitrate=3697.2kbits/s speed=1.03x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  202 fps= 24 q=22.0 size=    3584kB time=00:00:08.19 bitrate=3582.0kbits/s speed=0.994x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  209 fps= 24 q=20.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:08.47 bitrate=3711.7kbits/s speed=0.968x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  218 fps= 24 q=20.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:08.82 bitrate=3565.2kbits/s speed=0.953x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  219 fps= 22 q=20.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:08.89 bitrate=3537.3kbits/s speed=0.912x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  235 fps= 23 q=20.0 size=    4096kB time=00:00:09.49 bitrate=3533.2kbits/s speed=0.922x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  236 fps= 22 q=21.0 size=    4096kB time=00:00:09.54 bitrate=3516.0kbits/s speed=0.884x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  246 fps= 22 q=21.0 size=    4352kB time=00:00:09.93 bitrate=3587.4kbits/s speed=0.878x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  255 fps= 21 q=23.0 size=    4352kB time=00:00:10.30 bitrate=3458.1kbits/s speed=0.869x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  262 fps= 21 q=21.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:10.58 bitrate=3565.2kbits/s speed=0.856x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  268 fps= 21 q=21.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:10.82 bitrate=3488.7kbits/s speed=0.839x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  277 fps= 21 q=20.0 size=    4864kB time=00:00:11.19 bitrate=3560.2kbits/s speed=0.835x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  285 fps= 20 q=22.0 size=    4864kB time=00:00:11.51 bitrate=3459.7kbits/s speed=0.828x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  291 fps= 20 q=22.0 size=    5120kB time=00:00:11.74 bitrate=3569.9kbits/s speed=0.813x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  311 fps= 21 q=20.0 size=    5376kB time=00:00:12.53 bitrate=3512.4kbits/s speed=0.839x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  314 fps= 20 q=19.0 size=    5376kB time=00:00:12.67 bitrate=3473.8kbits/s speed=0.819x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  328 fps= 21 q=21.0 size=    5632kB time=00:00:13.23 bitrate=3485.9kbits/s speed=0.828x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  351 fps= 21 q=19.0 size=    6144kB time=00:00:14.14 bitrate=3559.3kbits/s speed=0.858x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  363 fps= 21 q=20.0 size=    6144kB time=00:00:14.62 bitrate=3440.7kbits/s speed=0.861x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  368 fps= 21 q=22.0 size=    6400kB time=00:00:14.83 bitrate=3533.5kbits/s speed=0.847x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  383 fps= 21 q=20.0 size=    6656kB time=00:00:15.41 bitrate=3536.5kbits/s speed=0.856x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  402 fps= 22 q=19.0 size=    6912kB time=00:00:16.18 bitrate=3498.7kbits/s speed=0.874x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  410 fps= 22 q=18.0 size=    6912kB time=00:00:16.50 bitrate=3429.8kbits/s speed=0.866x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  424 fps= 22 q=20.0 size=    7168kB time=00:00:17.06 bitrate=3440.7kbits/s speed=0.871x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  436 fps= 22 q=20.0 size=    7424kB time=00:00:17.55 bitrate=3464.6kbits/s speed=0.873x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  458 fps= 22 q=20.0 size=    7680kB time=00:00:18.43 bitrate=3412.5kbits/s speed=0.895x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  461 fps= 22 q=21.0 size=    7680kB time=00:00:18.55 bitrate=3391.1kbits/s speed=0.878x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  484 fps= 22 q=20.0 size=    8192kB time=00:00:19.45 bitrate=3448.9kbits/s speed= 0.9x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  489 fps= 22 q=20.0 size=    8192kB time=00:00:19.66 bitrate=3412.2kbits/s speed=0.888x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  503 fps= 22 q=17.0 size=    8448kB time=00:00:20.22 bitrate=3421.9kbits/s speed=0.893x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  524 fps= 23 q=20.0 size=    8960kB time=00:00:21.06 bitrate=3485.2kbits/s speed=0.909x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  537 fps= 23 q=19.0 size=    8960kB time=00:00:21.59 bitrate=3399.0kbits/s speed=0.912x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  548 fps= 23 q=20.0 size=    9216kB time=00:00:22.03 bitrate=3426.2kbits/s speed=0.91x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  554 fps= 22 q=20.0 size=    9216kB time=00:00:22.26 bitrate=3390.4kbits/s speed=0.901x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  566 fps= 22 q=21.0 size=    9472kB time=00:00:22.75 bitrate=3409.9kbits/s speed=0.902x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  585 fps= 23 q=19.0 size=    9728kB time=00:00:23.49 bitrate=3391.4kbits/s speed=0.913x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  598 fps= 23 q=20.0 size=    9984kB time=00:00:24.03 bitrate=3403.3kbits/s speed=0.916x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  606 fps= 23 q=20.0 size=    9984kB time=00:00:24.35 bitrate=3357.8kbits/s speed=0.91x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  624 fps= 23 q=20.0 size=   10496kB time=00:00:25.07 bitrate=3428.7kbits/s speed=0.92x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  631 fps= 23 q=20.0 size=   10496kB time=00:00:25.35 bitrate=3391.0kbits/s speed=0.912x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  649 fps= 23 q=20.0 size=   10752kB time=00:00:26.07 bitrate=3377.8kbits/s speed=0.922x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  654 fps= 23 q=21.0 size=   10752kB time=00:00:26.26 bitrate=3354.0kbits/s speed=0.912x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  674 fps= 23 q=20.0 size=   11264kB time=00:00:27.07 bitrate=3408.2kbits/s speed=0.924x    
I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  688 fps= 23 q=22.0 size=   11520kB time=00:00:27.63
```

Answer (score 1):

The only alternative I found is to use the MediaCoder library, but it's quite rough to use. I found that great repo that handle all the heavy lifting for us : https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/Mp4Composer-android
It allows to scale perfectly a mp4 and tests result in 7 seconds execution time for a 1 min video. So way better than FFMPEG and closer to what I expected.